# Which languages allow importing non-rectangular data to plot

Tags: python, r, matlab, plot

I often have to deal with data from multiple experimental runs that have different x-axis sizes. My data may look like this for instance.

```
[1 2 3 4]  
[5 6]  
[7 8 9 10 15]  
[4]
```

This means that most languages (e.g. Matlab) either have a tough time reading in the data, or aren't very plotting friendly (e.g. Java). Can anyone suggest a language that makes importing, manipulating, and plotting data easy? I just switched to Python with numpy/scipy but I haven't found that too helpful (I just like using Python). Please just post about this specific functionality as opposed to blanket statements about the language.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "different x-axis sizes"?

Comment: Data may look like the following
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6]
[7 8 9 10 15]
[4]
where each set of brackets is a row. So you don't get a rectangular 2d array.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Would it work to say "data from multiple experimental runs with differing numbers of results"? And what file format are you working with?

Comment: It's all typical ascii data, .txt or .csv for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt in the [free, open-source statistical programming language R](http://cran.r-project.org) - I'll try to update as I get more specifics about your data.

As an example data file, I'm using a .txt with these lines:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6
7, 8, 9, 10, 15
4
```

To read in the data, I'd write:

```
# Always set this option - trust me
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# This read each line of the file into a vector of strings
x <- readLines(con = file("blah.txt"))

# Split by whatever your delimiter is
xlist <-strsplit(x, ", ")

# Now, each experiment's data is an element in xlist
# It'll be easiest to plot if you get the whole thing into a data.frame
# I'm certain there's a more elegant way to do this, but...
# Name the elements of xlist (kludge)
names(xlist) <- c("Experiment 1", "Experiment 2", 
                  "Experiment 3", "Experiment 4")

# Convert each experiment's data into a data.frame, then stack
# I like using the package plyr for this
library(plyr)

dat <- ldply(names(xlist), .fun = function(expname) {

      data.frame(exp = expname,
                 result = xlist[[expname]])

})


# Check out the data.frame to make sure everything came through okay
str(dat)

# Might need to convert a string to a numeric...
dat$result <- as.numeric(dat$result)


# Then plot (for which I'd use ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)

# All results together
ggplot(dat, aes(x = result)) + geom_histogram()

# By experiment
ggplot(dat, aes(x = result)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap( ~ expname)

# Overlaid densities - doesn't work if an experiment has very few results
ggplot(dat, aes(x = result, color = expname)) + geom_density()
```

No doubt there's a more elegant way to do this, but this is the general flow in R - read it in as a list (doesn't need rectangular data), convert it to molten-format data (inherently rectangular), plot.

Answer (score 2):

In R you can read in regular data with the fll=TRUE parameter to read.table:

```
 txt <-"[1 2 3 4]  
 [5 6]  
 [7 8 9 10 15]  
 [4] "
```

The "[...]" is perhps an XML or Matlabe formalism? The R convention is to use end of lines and we need to remove the square-brackets, a regex-gsub function is used:

```
read.table(text=gsub("\\[|\\]", "", readLines(textConnection(txt)) ), 
           fill=TRUE, header=FALSE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  2  3  4 NA
2  5  6 NA NA NA
3  7  8  9 10 15
4  4 NA NA NA NA
```

The barplot function seems what you might be expecting. This give one barplot per row of data:

```
apply(dl, 1, function(x) barplot(x[!is.na(x)] )  )
```

If you wanted them all on one figure then perhaps:

```
matplot(x=1:4, dl, type="b", ylim=c(0,20),  
        col=c("red", "orange", "blue", "green", "purple"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While the regular 2D matrices in MATLAB are rectangular, cell arrays can have different length arrays in each cell.  In a sense they are just a convenient way of packaging different 1d arrays  together.

At a more basic level you can call a plot with multiple arrays, e.g.

```
plot(x1,y1,'+',x2,y2,'*',...)
```

where `x1`, and `y2` match in size, but `x2` can be different from `x1`.  You can also construct a cell array, and plot that with one simple command:

```
C = cell(2,3);
C{1,1} = x1; C{2,1} = y2;
C{1,2} = x2; etc
plot(C{:})
```

In `numpy`, `pyplot.plot()` has the same syntax.  `x1` etc could be items in Python lists.  Or the arrays could be elements in a numpy object array:

```
array([[[1 2 3 4 5], [2 3 4], [0 2 4 6]],
       [[4 5 6 7 8], [-2 -3 -4], [-3 -1  1  3]]], dtype=object)

for i in range(3):
    pyplot.plot(*C[:,i])
    pyplot.hold('on')
```

You can also plot multiple lines by concatenating all the data, with `None` separators.  This seems to help (speed wise) when there are a very large number of lines.  Wrapping the data in an `np.array` is optional (though `pyplot` does that internally).

```
pyplot.plot(*np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,None,1,2.5,4,5], [1,3,2,5,1,None,2,4,5,6]]))
pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4,5,None,1,2.5,4,5], [1,3,2,5,1,None,2,4,5,6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at RSI IDL? It handles array slicing very smoothly and has a ton of plotting methods built in. It's my favorite analysis tool for prototyping solutions in the lab.

http://www.exelisvis.com/ProductsServices/IDL.aspx